# Long (recursive) tracebacks when passing an error with future.set_exception(err)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am having trouble understanding how python's traceback works together with asyncio.
I have a function that accepts requests to be processed later in a batch. The error may occur while processing the batch and I use `future.set_exception(err)` to communicate the error to all callers.
For some reason, it generates ridiculously long tracebacks (depends on a batch length).

Here is a minimum code to reproduce it:

```py
import asyncio

batch = []
batch_len = 10

async def process():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    batch.append(future)
    if len(batch) >= batch_len:
        await process_batch()
    return await future

async def process_batch():
    try:
        # Here I call some outer service. Let's pretend it raises an error.
        raise RuntimeError("Oops")
    except Exception as err:
        for future in batch:
            # Pass an error to all callers
            future.set_exception(err)

async def main():
    futures = (process() for _ in range(batch_len))
    await asyncio.gather(*futures) # raises on first unsuccessful request

asyncio.run(main())
```

The output: (problematic part marked)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../fut1.py", line 27, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File ".../python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File ".../python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File ".../fut1.py", line 25, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*futures) # raises on first unsuccessful request
  File ".../fut1.py", line 12, in process  \
    return await future                    |
  File ".../fut1.py", line 12, in process  |
    return await future                    |  HERE IT IS
  File ".../fut1.py", line 12, in process  |
    return await future                    |
  [Previous line repeated 7 more times]    /
  File ".../fut1.py", line 17, in process_batch
    raise RuntimeError("Oops")
RuntimeError: Oops
```

Not sure why this recursive part appears here and how to avoid it.
I will be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think this unexpected behaviour stems from a subtle mistake in `process`. You are not returning the future, but the *result* of the future. Meaning your coroutines will yield on the `await future` part, waiting for a result, before the resulting coroutines can be collected by `asyncio.gather`. This way the `RuntimeError` is actually raised within `process` when you are unpacking your generator and not just set as a result for the collected coroutines in `gather`. This is why you get 10 times the same exception in the same line of code in your traceback.
Maybe this slightly changed piece of code leads to a more expected behaviour:

```
import asyncio

batch = []
batch_len = 10

async def process():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    batch.append(future)
    if len(batch) >= batch_len:
        await process_batch()
    # return the future without awaiting, otherwise exception is raised here
    return future 

async def process_batch():
    try:
        # Here I call some outer service. Let's pretend it raises an error.
        raise RuntimeError("Oops")
    except Exception as err:
        for future in batch:
            # Pass an error to all callers
            future.set_exception(err)

async def main():
    futures = (process() for _ in range(batch_len))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*futures) # raises on first unsuccessful request
    print(*results, sep="\n")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Actually, this `return await future` was on purpose. In the case of `return future` the return value would be `Awaitable[Awaitable[T]]` which just masks the problem... Calling `process()` returns a coroutine object which is `Awaitable` and resolves either to some value or to an error, but it shouldn't raise an error upon call. I tried to wrap generator with `[]` which makes sure that awaitables were created before calling `gather`, same result. But if you remove `try... except` and set `future.set_exception(RuntimeError())` - all fine. Something shady is happening with traceback.

Comment: I think what is happening with the traceback is, that normally exceptions are propagated up the callstack. But by setting the _same_ exception object in all futures, you're kind of propagating it sideways before it goes up again. Using a list on the generator doesn't make a difference. The exception is not raised in `gather` but while unpacking the generator with `*`. `gather` is never called in your example as I see it.

Comment: What makes you think it raised while unpacking? Out of curiosity, I tried to unpack them before: `[f0,f1,...,f9] = futures` and pass to `gather` as separate variables: `asyncio.gather(f0,f1,...,f9)`. It fails on `gather`, just like before (see original traceback). About sideways propagation.. yes, maybe. These futures are executed sequentially via event loop anyway. Maybe it's done via recursive calls internally, and that's why the call stack grows.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the unpacking. I made a mistake. I fiddled around with it yesterday but I couldn't really find out more about how the traceback is generated exactly. Hopefully someone with more insight can weigh in on this.